# Call a java class from perl

Tags: java, perl, call

I would like to call a java class from perl. I usually use the java class from command line to do some processing like:

```
java com.something.some
```

Now, I need to call it from inside a perl script.

Could you let me know how I can do it?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is simple enough - you just use the [system](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/system.html) command to execute an arbitrary command line, e.g.

```
system("java com.something.Some")
```

Answer (score 23):

The [`Java` library](http://search.cpan.org/dist/Java/) lets you to easily 
integrate Java calls in Perl code.

e.g.

```
use Java;
$java = new Java;
$obj = $java->create_object("com.my.Class","constructor parameter");
$obj->myMethod("method parameter");
$obj->setId(5);
```

Comment: Interesting... the integration there is quite impressive.  This is probably overkill for the task in the question, but the ability to interact with Java codebases at a deeper level than just `main` methods is intriguing.

Answer (score 6):

[Inline::Java](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Inline::Java) is a well known module for Java/Perl integration.  It simplifies embedding Java in Perl code as well as the converse: embedding Perl into Java.

View the Cpan perldoc for more information on how to use this module.